# Gwt Material Design: MaterialSlider not working in classic dev mode

Tags: gwt, gwt-material-design

Here is the exception that gets displayed on the Browser.

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:423) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:530)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null)
>   @gwt.material.design.jquery.client.api.JQuery::$(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Element;)([JavaScript
>   object(8)]): null at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:252)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:121)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:573)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:293)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>   at gwt.material.design.jquery.client.api.JQuery.$(JQuery.java) at
>   gwt.material.design.jquery.client.api.JQuery.$(JQuery.java:167) at
>   gwt.material.design.client.base.MaterialWidget.$this(MaterialWidget.java:157)
>   at
>   com.mdesign.vadiraj.client.MaterialDesignWithCarousel.onModuleLoad(MaterialDesignWithCarousel.java:32)
>   ... 9 more

Here is the exception from Eclipse console.

> 14:34:14.799 [ERROR] [materialdesignwithcarousel] Unable to load
>   module entry point class
>   com.mdesign.vadiraj.client.MaterialDesignWithCarousel (see associated
>   exception for details)
>
> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null)
>   @gwt.material.design.jquery.client.api.JQuery::$(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Element;)([JavaScript
>   object(8)]): null
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:252)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:121)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:573)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>       at gwt.material.design.jquery.client.api.JQuery.$(JQuery.java)
>       at gwt.material.design.jquery.client.api.JQuery.$(JQuery.java:167)
>       at gwt.material.design.client.base.MaterialWidget.$this(MaterialWidget.java:157)
>       at com.mdesign.vadiraj.client.MaterialDesignWithCarousel.onModuleLoad(MaterialDesignWithCarousel.java:32)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:423)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:530)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

This is my project setup - Java 1.8 | GWT 2.8.1 | Classic dev-mode

> inherits name="gwt.material.design.jquery.JQuery"
>
> inherits name='gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialWithJQuery'
>
> inherits name="gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialDesignBasic"

Attaching the code snippet from the Entrypoint class

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    MaterialSlider slider = new MaterialSlider();
    RootPanel.get().add(slider);

    slider.add(new Label("safrfsdhhdf"));
    slider.add(new Button("I am a button"));
    slider.add(new TextArea());
    slider.add(new MaterialSwitch(true));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT Material Design uses JsInterop which doesn't work in legacy dev mode (nobody should continue to use legacy dev mode these days anyway, it's been deprecated for years)

Comment: To clarify slightly - there's no problem with using it, as long as you don't want to use any new features either, like Java 8+ support or JsInterop. For legacy projects that just want to keep using the exact same tooling and same features, it remains supported. We want to encourage those projects to still use latest GWT (for security updates, etc) even with legacy Dev Mode, but it you want to actually use the new features added in recent releases, you need to upgrade how you use your tools too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have been trying to move to superdev mode. It has its own disadvantages as there is no support for `1. Hot code replace (Which is supported by Classic dev mode) `

`2. Inspect variable values while debugging. (Which again supported by classic dev mode)`